# How to avoid horizontal scrollbar when using angular material grid list?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat grid list inside a component, similar to this:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="650px" gutterSize="10px">
<mat-grid-tile
  *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
  [colspan]="tile.cols"
  [rowspan]="tile.rows"
  [style.background]="tile.color"
>
  {{tile.text}}
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Whenever I give it a height superior to 200px, it automatically adds an horizontal scrollbar and I do not why or how to avoid it.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was not actually the mat grid list but a parent componenet. It had lateral padding configured to 20px and whenever the page height increased it added it the lateral scroll. Set padding to zero and it was fixed